# Google reCaptcha - how do I make it so that the user can't click a button unless the reCaptcha is submitted?

Tags: html, recaptcha

I've been trying to add a recaptcha to my website and I've added the widget but here's the problem - the user can click the submit button before finishing the recaptcha and that just defeats the whole purpose of having a recaptcha at all.

How can I make the button appear only when the reCaptcha is finished?

Screenshots are attached, thanks in advance

```
    <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif">Shorten a URL!</h1>
    <form action="/shortenurl" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="URL..."/>
      <iframe title="reCAPTCHA" src="boring recaptcha" role="presentation" name="a-3dswbffhbuei" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-storage-access-by-user-activation" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <input id="sm" type="submit" value="Shorten URL!" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You need back-end code that verifies the recaptcha. HTML isn't enough. Have you read the docs? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Comment: @Tiffany ah thanks, i'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

just add the required attribute in input tag

```html
<input type="text" name="url" placeholder="URL..." required/>
```

Comment: the user can still press the submit button without completing the recaptcha :(

Comment: ah yes, thanks but that makes sure that the user inputs the URL. i want it to make sure that the *recaptcha* is done before the submit button is pressed, or it could just hide the submit button until the recaptcha is done or something.

Comment: cannot find the desired solution. I would use custom captcha instead of google captcha. Try using your own custom captcha code